# exists().click not working with karate 0.9.6.RC3 version

Tags: automation, karate

I was using 0.9.6.RC2 till now the below code works fine for this version

```
* exists("a[title='tn3270e: xyz']").click
```

But today i changed the version to 0.9.6.RC3 and i am getting below error

```
TypeError: exists("a[title='tn3270e: xyz']").click is not a function in <eval>
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized exists() has been updated.
docs here
https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#optional

so now the code will be

```
optional("a[title='tn3270e: xyz']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

if normal click not working with optional then I have used * optional mouse().click() which is not working , any alternative click() method available while using optional